# Video JS- Adding a alternate Audio Track in a video file

Tags: javascript, html, audio, video, video.js

I have a video (URL=https://bitmovin-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8) having two audio Source (english and dubbing). I want to add alternate audio test(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-sound/3.0.7/sounds/glass.mp3) to that video. I am using Video.js to play the video. I have used this link -([How do i add multiple audio tracks from my array list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56721713/how-do-i-add-multiple-audio-tracks-from-my-array-list)) to add alternate track in video and i am able to add the track in the video. But when i am switching the track using the change track Icon to test it is not playing the audio in the video while there is no issue in english and dubbing tracks.
'''

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.7.6/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>

  <video id="maat-player" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls width="500px" height="350px">
    <source src="https://bitmovin-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL">
  </video>
  <div id="audioTrackChoice">

  </div>
  <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.7.6/video.js"></script>

  <script>
    (function (window, videojs) {
      var player = window.player = videojs('maat-player');
      var audioTrackList = player.audioTracks();
      ////////////////////////////add new audi track code//////////
      const usersAudioTrackList = [{
        id: '1',
        kind: 'translation',
        label: 'test',
        language: 'kannada',
        audio: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-sound/3.0.7/sounds/glass.mp3',
      }];

      ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      var audioTrackSelect = document.getElementById("audioTrackChoice");

      audioTrackSelect.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        var track = audioTrackList[event.target.id]; console.log(audioTrackList);
        console.log('User switched to track ' + track.label);
        track.enabled = true; console.log(event.target.id);
      });


      audioTrackList.on('click', function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < audioTrackList.length; i++) {
          var track = audioTrackList[i];
          if (track.enabled) {
            console.log('A new ' + track.label + ' has been enabled!');
          }
        }
      });


      audioTrackList.on('addtrack', function () {
        console.log('a track has been added to the audio track list');
      });




      audioTrackList.on('removetrack', function () {
        console.log('a track has been removed from the audio track list');
      });


      player.on('loadeddata', function () {
        console.log('There are ' + audioTrackList.length + ' audio tracks');
        usersAudioTrackList.forEach(track => {

          player.audioTracks().addTrack(
            new videojs.AudioTrack(track) // Create a track object.
          );
        });
        for (var i = 0; i < audioTrackList.length; i++) {
          var track = audioTrackList[i];
          //var option = document.createElement("option");
          var elem = document.createElement('input');
          elem.type = 'button';
          elem.value = track.label;
          elem.id = i;
          if (track.enabled) {
            elem.selected = true;
          }
          audioTrackSelect.append(elem);
          console.log('Track ' + (i + 1));
          ['label', 'enabled', 'language', 'id', 'kind'].forEach(function (prop) {
            console.log("  " + prop + ": " + track[prop]);
          });

        }
      });
    }(window, window.videojs));


  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

'''
How can we play my alternate audio in the video. Saw few post in Video Js stating its not possible to merge audio and video using video.js. If this is the case can anyone help me in getting library for merging audio and Video.

Working fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/hariommishra/f0e4nbs5/1/

Answer (score 0):

[Video.js](https://docs.videojs.com/#) is only used to play videos. It only detects the audio track which are already in video file. It does not help us to add new external audio track to the video file.

```js
      ////////////////////////////add new audi track code//////////
      const usersAudioTrackList = [{
        id: '1',
        kind: 'translation',
        label: 'test',
        language: 'kannada',
        audio: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-sound/3.0.7/sounds/glass.mp3',
      }];
```

There is no `audio` key in Audio track list of video.js. You can visit this tutorial (https://docs.videojs.com/tutorial-audio-tracks.html).