# HTML Video Element Play Multiple Audio Tracks from Single Video

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, html5-audio

Problem: HTML video element plays a video with the first audio stream. But the video has multiple streams to be played or selected.

The video is recorded with OBS and has one video stream and 6 audio streams.

Question: How can I determine which audio stream to play? And can I play multiple streams?

These are the streams that the video has. Read with ffprobe

```
[{"index":0,"codec_name":"h264","codec_long_name":"H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10","profile":"High","codec_type":"video","codec_time_base":"1/120","codec_tag_string":"avc1","codec_tag":"0x31637661","width":1920,"height":1080,"coded_width":1920,"coded_height":1088,"closed_captions":0,"has_b_frames":1,"sample_aspect_ratio":"1:1","display_aspect_ratio":"16:9","pix_fmt":"yuv420p","level":42,"color_range":"tv","color_space":"smpte170m","color_transfer":"smpte170m","color_primaries":"smpte170m","chroma_location":"left","refs":1,"is_avc":"true","nal_length_size":"4","r_frame_rate":"60/1","avg_frame_rate":"60/1","time_base":"1/15360","start_pts":0,"start_time":"0.000000","duration_ts":283904,"duration":"18.483333","bit_rate":"15000014","bits_per_raw_sample":"8","nb_frames":"1109","disposition":{"default":1,"dub":0,"original":0,"comment":0,"lyrics":0,"karaoke":0,"forced":0,"hearing_impaired":0,"visual_impaired":0,"clean_effects":0,"attached_pic":0,"timed_thumbnails":0},"tags":{"language":"und","handler_name":"VideoHandler"}},
{"index":1,"codec_name":"aac","codec_long_name":"AAC (Advanced Audio Coding)","profile":"LC","codec_type":"audio","codec_time_base":"1/44100","codec_tag_string":"mp4a","codec_tag":"0x6134706d","sample_fmt":"fltp","sample_rate":"44100","channels":2,"channel_layout":"stereo","bits_per_sample":0,"r_frame_rate":"0/0","avg_frame_rate":"0/0","time_base":"1/44100","start_pts":0,"start_time":"0.000000","duration_ts":813056,"duration":"18.436644","bit_rate":"9905","max_bit_rate":"320000","nb_frames":"795","disposition":{"default":1,"dub":0,"original":0,"comment":0,"lyrics":0,"karaoke":0,"forced":0,"hearing_impaired":0,"visual_impaired":0,"clean_effects":0,"attached_pic":0,"timed_thumbnails":0},"tags":{"language":"und","handler_name":"SoundHandler"}},
{"index":2,"codec_name":"aac","codec_long_name":"AAC (Advanced Audio Coding)","profile":"LC","codec_type":"audio","codec_time_base":"1/44100","codec_tag_string":"mp4a","codec_tag":"0x6134706d","sample_fmt":"fltp","sample_rate":"44100","channels":2,"channel_layout":"stereo","bits_per_sample":0,"r_frame_rate":"0/0","avg_frame_rate":"0/0","time_base":"1/44100","start_pts":0,"start_time":"0.000000","duration_ts":813056,"duration":"18.436644","bit_rate":"9787","max_bit_rate":"320000","nb_frames":"795","disposition":{"default":0,"dub":0,"original":0,"comment":0,"lyrics":0,"karaoke":0,"forced":0,"hearing_impaired":0,"visual_impaired":0,"clean_effects":0,"attached_pic":0,"timed_thumbnails":0},"tags":{"language":"und","handler_name":"SoundHandler"}},
{"index":3,"codec_name":"aac","codec_long_name":"AAC (Advanced Audio Coding)","profile":"LC","codec_type":"audio","codec_time_base":"1/44100","codec_tag_string":"mp4a","codec_tag":"0x6134706d","sample_fmt":"fltp","sample_rate":"44100","channels":2,"channel_layout":"stereo","bits_per_sample":0,"r_frame_rate":"0/0","avg_frame_rate":"0/0","time_base":"1/44100","start_pts":0,"start_time":"0.000000","duration_ts":813056,"duration":"18.436644","bit_rate":"2091","max_bit_rate":"160000","nb_frames":"795","disposition":{"default":0,"dub":0,"original":0,"comment":0,"lyrics":0,"karaoke":0,"forced":0,"hearing_impaired":0,"visual_impaired":0,"clean_effects":0,"attached_pic":0,"timed_thumbnails":0},"tags":{"language":"und","handler_name":"SoundHandler"}},
{"index":4,"codec_name":"aac","codec_long_name":"AAC (Advanced Audio Coding)","profile":"LC","codec_type":"audio","codec_time_base":"1/44100","codec_tag_string":"mp4a","codec_tag":"0x6134706d","sample_fmt":"fltp","sample_rate":"44100","channels":2,"channel_layout":"stereo","bits_per_sample":0,"r_frame_rate":"0/0","avg_frame_rate":"0/0","time_base":"1/44100","start_pts":0,"start_time":"0.000000","duration_ts":813056,"duration":"18.436644","bit_rate":"2091","max_bit_rate":"160000","nb_frames":"795","disposition":{"default":0,"dub":0,"original":0,"comment":0,"lyrics":0,"karaoke":0,"forced":0,"hearing_impaired":0,"visual_impaired":0,"clean_effects":0,"attached_pic":0,"timed_thumbnails":0},"tags":{"language":"und","handler_name":"SoundHandler"}},
{"index":5,"codec_name":"aac","codec_long_name":"AAC (Advanced Audio Coding)","profile":"LC","codec_type":"audio","codec_time_base":"1/44100","codec_tag_string":"mp4a","codec_tag":"0x6134706d","sample_fmt":"fltp","sample_rate":"44100","channels":2,"channel_layout":"stereo","bits_per_sample":0,"r_frame_rate":"0/0","avg_frame_rate":"0/0","time_base":"1/44100","start_pts":0,"start_time":"0.000000","duration_ts":813056,"duration":"18.436644","bit_rate":"2091","max_bit_rate":"160000","nb_frames":"795","disposition":{"default":0,"dub":0,"original":0,"comment":0,"lyrics":0,"karaoke":0,"forced":0,"hearing_impaired":0,"visual_impaired":0,"clean_effects":0,"attached_pic":0,"timed_thumbnails":0},"tags":{"language":"und","handler_name":"SoundHandler"}},
{"index":6,"codec_name":"aac","codec_long_name":"AAC (Advanced Audio Coding)","profile":"LC","codec_type":"audio","codec_time_base":"1/44100","codec_tag_string":"mp4a","codec_tag":"0x6134706d","sample_fmt":"fltp","sample_rate":"44100","channels":2,"channel_layout":"stereo","bits_per_sample":0,"r_frame_rate":"0/0","avg_frame_rate":"0/0","time_base":"1/44100","start_pts":0,"start_time":"0.000000","duration_ts":813056,"duration":"18.436644","bit_rate":"2091","max_bit_rate":"160000","nb_frames":"795","disposition":{"default":0,"dub":0,"original":0,"comment":0,"lyrics":0,"karaoke":0,"forced":0,"hearing_impaired":0,"visual_impaired":0,"clean_effects":0,"attached_pic":0,"timed_thumbnails":0},"tags":{"language":"und","handler_name":"SoundHandler"}}]
```

Comment: There is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/audioTracks but the browser support is still very low unfortunately... The best is still probably to serve each track independently and to merge them yourself using MSE. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64839836/playing-one-of-multiple-audio-tracks-in-sync-with-a-video/64852201#64852201

Comment: If you can use VideoJS (or similar) this may help:https://stackoverflow.com/a/58185992/334402